# How does IntelliJ IDEA know the port number of the running Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, jmx

When using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, launching a Spring Boot project automatically displays the port number in the IDE.

I would like to understand the principle behind this.

[image]

Even when I set server.port=0 in the configuration file and turn off the output logs, IntelliJ IDEA still manages to recognize the port number. It is said online that this information is obtained from JMX. Indeed, when I disable the JMX endpoints in the IDEA run configuration, the port number is no longer recognized. However, when I use JConsole to inspect all properties of the running Spring Boot project, none of the values match the startup port number.

[image]

Comment: I don't know the source code of intellij but anyone who starts a process (with java ...) can read the process id and then with that process id find the port it is running on (this would be a logical way of going about it - meaning I would expect Intellij to do it in a similar manner)

Comment: I may not have been precise in what I said. What I want to get is the port number for web-related services after Spring Boot starts. However, the project may listen on multiple ports, and the approach you mentioned cannot automatically distinguish which one is the web port.

Comment: can you state exactly what your question is? Cause til now I thought your question is `I would like to understand the principle behind this.` and now I simply don't understand what you want to achieve... A single process can listen to many ports, and with the method I mentioned you still can see which ports it listens to (even if several), they will still show which process id is listening

Comment: If I configure server.port=14000 and I use netty to listen on port 14101, your method can know that the process is listening on ports 14000 and 14101, but how do I know which of these two values corresponds to server.port

Comment: So your way is definitely not the way intellj idea uses it.

Comment: in my way I wouldnt care what u wrote in properties, I look at the end result in the system and then ask the OS which ports are being listened to by the process.

Comment: 你说的这种方式我之前用过，
[这里](https://github.com/GG22G2/compile-listener/blob/master/src/main/java/hsb/compile/springboot/SpringBootDevtool.java)
我使用netstat -ano命令获取指定进程的监听端口列表，但这不是我需要的